# CiviCRM Managing Contacts in a Group

Tags: groups, evaluating-civicrm, civirules

I face difficultly validating individual contacts to a group who must be a member of its parent group. 
For Example I have groups such as *sales executive-north, sales executive-east,sales executive-west*. All these have *Sale Executives* as there parent group.

Case 1 : Whenever I add new individual contact to any of the three subgroups, the system have validate/notify  that the  contact have to a member of *Sale Executives* group first.

Case 2: Whenever I  remove a member from *Sale Executives* group then they have to be removed from its subgroups also.

Is there way to control this through Civirules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, parent groups work the other round to the way you are trying to use them: you don't add someone to the parent and then to a child group; but instead you add them to a child group and they are regarded as a member of the parent group.

In your case, by adding someone to the Sales Executive-North group, they are automatically part of the Sales Executive parent group.  Similarly when you remove them from the child group, they are no longer part of the parent group (unless they were also in another child group).

As an alternative to parent groups you could use smart groups.

Comment: I was going to suggest Smart Groups too. Ie you have all the 'child' groups and then make a Smart Group that contains all those in your child groups.